# Fetching unique records from duplicate data without using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some problem  with **GROUP BY**. For some reason I cannot use it. So I am looking for some alternative solution. I am using online webhosting  and with **GROUP BY** I am getting this error:

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'denieuwe_db.guest.gid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

**Bit Intro:** I am making a restaurant website and in the **Guest** table I have all the **guest_code** which is unique. Inside the **purchase** table there are all the purchases of the guest with **purchaseid & guest_code**

**Table:** Purchase

```
+------------------------+
|purchaseid | guest_code | 
+------------------------+
|    1      | CUST7408668|   
|    2      | CUST7408668|    
|    3      | CUST4425874| 
|    4      | CUST4425874|   
|    5      | CUST4425874|  
+------------------------+
```

**Table:** guest

```
    +-----------------------------------+
    |   gid     | guest_code |   Name   |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |    1      | CUST7408668|    Mia   |     
    |    5      | CUST4425874|    zoi   |
    +------------------------+----------+
```

**SQL:**

```
     SELECT purchase.purchaseid,
            purchase.guest_code, 
            guest.guest_code,
            guest.name,    
     FROM purchase
     INNER JOIN guest ON purchase.guest_code=guest.guest_code GROUP BY purchase.guest_code;
```

**What I want in result:**

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
|purchaseid | guest_code |   name   |  gid  | guest_code | 
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
|    1      | CUST7408668|    Mia   |   1   | CUST7408668|
|    3      | CUST4425874|    zoi   |   5   | CUST4425874|
+------------------------+----------+--------------------+
```

**I am getting exact result using GROUP BY on localhost** but getting a problem on my hosting with it. So I am looking for alternative solution. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want the minimum purchase ID. You can use `min()` for that. You might also need to extend the `GROUP BY` clause with the other columns.

```
SELECT min(purchase.purchaseid) purchaseid,
       purchase.guest_code,
       guest.guest_code,
       guest.name
       FROM purchase
            INNER JOIN guest
                       ON purchase.guest_code = guest.guest_code
       GROUP BY purchase.guest_code,
                guest.guest_code,
                guest.name;
```

Comment: remove the comma from the last fetch column  guest.name, else this is my answer! Thankyou so much for this.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate before joining:

```
 SELECT p.purchaseid, p.guest_code, g.name,    
 FROM (SELECT MIN(p.purchaseid) as purchaseid, p.guest_code
       FROM purchase p
       GROUP BY p.guest_code
      ) p JOIN
      guest g
      ON p.guest_code = g.guest_code;
```

Comment: #1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'denieuwe_db.g.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Thnakyou so much for posting your answer.

Comment: @navjotsingh . . . The outer query shouldn't have the `GROUP BY`.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Distinct on purchase table guest code to remove duplicate data, since you are not doing any aggregation

```
SELECT DISTINCT( purchase.guest_code ), 
               purchase.purchaseid, 
               guest.guest_code, 
               guest.NAME, 
FROM   purchase 
       INNER JOIN guest 
               ON purchase.guest_code = guest.guest_code
```

Comment: can you so me how to by giving an suitable example?

Comment: added example for the above query

Comment: I appreciate you contribution but this is not what am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

may be one simplest way, using only guest_code in the group by because its related.

```
  SELECT MIN(purchase.purchaseid) AS purchaseid,
     purchase.guest_code, 
     guest.Name,
     guest.gid,  
     guest.guest_code
  FROM purchase
  INNER JOIN guest 
  ON purchase.guest_code=guest.guest_code 
  GROUP BY purchase.guest_code
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I contacted the Webhost technical team and this is what they say about this issue.

> Hi,
>
> on shared hosting this is not allowed as you change the database
>   server behavior for ALL other websites.
>
> But you can tweak your SQL queries to get a similar behavior by using
>   ANY_VALUE() for each nonaggregated column.
>
> eg.
>
> SELECT name, address, MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
>
> fails, because address is not in the GROUP BY.
>
> using:
>
> SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
>
> works on the other side and produces similar result to disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
>
> Explanation from MySQL:
>
> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
>   want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses. Disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some
>   property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
>   named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.
>
> You can achieve the same effect without disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
>   by using ANY_VALUE() to refer to the nonaggregated column.